# Graph API: Posting to Application Wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to post to the Application Wall like this:

`POST APPLICATION_ID/feed with the valid access token in params.`

eg.

Action

`POST http://graph.facebook.com/128054470604109/feed`

Data:

`"link=http://apps.facebook.com/flohdev/events/4dd6014e62be660001000002&name=Floh&access_token=XXXX"`

The exception I get is:

`"type"=>"OAuthException",`
`"message"=>"(#200) This API call requires a valid app_id."`
`

The app has office access permission and I'm logged in as the Administrator while doing this. Is there something I'm missing here.

**UPDATE**
Turns out there is a bug in the Mogli library where it doesn't pass the access_token. A manual curl works fine.

Comment: try removing "/" at the starting of the application ID and try this " 128054470604109/feed/ "

Comment: Aby - I've updated the POST action with the full url

Comment: do you have valid Access Token.  May be your access token is expired.  Get "Offline Access" permission so that you can get infinite expiry time.

Comment: Yup, I have offline access and a valid fresh access token.

Comment: Turns out there is a bug in the Mogli library where it doesn't pass the access_token. A manual curl works fine.

Comment: which language u r working on??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there is a bug in the Ruby Mogli library where it doesn't pass the access_token. A manual curl with access token works fine.